# Concatenate pdfs without losing bookmarks

Tags: linux, pdf

I have two pdfs, `A.pdf` and `B.pdf`, each of which has some bookmarks (perhaps added by [jpdfbookmarks](http://flavianopetrocchi.blogspot.com/)). I'd like to concatenate them into one big file, `AB.pdf`. So I tried one of my favorite tools, [pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/):

```
pdftk A.pdf B.pdf cat output AB.pdf
```

But then `AB.pdf` doesn't have any bookmarks! Is there some way to concatenate pdfs in such a way that you retain the bookmarks? I prefer a [Free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), or at least free, command-line tool that will work on linux.

Comment: See also: [Adobe Acrobat: How to batch to combine multiple pdf files? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/389760/adobe-acrobat-how-to-batch-to-combine-multiple-pdf-files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't actually tried it, but from the documentation it looks like [Multivalent](http://multivalent.sourceforge.net/) might do it.

jPdf Tweak seems to do it to but it's not command-line. (I can't post the link because I'm a new user but it's on Sourceforge)

Comment: "`java -classpath Multivalent20060102.jar tool.pdf.Merge -samedoc A.pdf B.pdf`" does the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Pdftk version 2.02 now merges bookmarks when concatenating PDFs, but only when whole PDF documents are being concatenated.