# Utility that can print documents and merge the output with several other PDF files

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, pdf, printing

I have a big book that consist of several static documents and a few dynamic ones (primarily Excel with links). The process of printing all this to one PDF as required by my customer takes way to much time.

What I want is a tool I can use in a batch file that will convert all documents in a folder to PDF and then merge all these PDFs to one big one. All the files have predictable names.

I've been thinking of GhostScript and a WScript, but that dosn't solve printing Excel documents to PDF. Hope you guys have some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For printing Excel documents to PDF... If you have Office 2007 or higher you can use the [VBscript here](http://www.thoughtasylum.com/blog/2012/12/20/vbscript-to-convert-microsoft-office-files-word-excel-powerp.html).

(You need to create a batch file which loops through your .xls end .docs calling this VBScript.)

After that you can merge the PDF's with [PDFTK](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) of or one of the tools from [Xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/) or use your own method with Ghostscript.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>This is only a partial answer since it doesn't answer the convert part</sub>

For batch merge you can try this CMD batch with PDFTK. 
The output file is always called *binder.pdf* but that is changeable to a generic name if you need it.

Read [full instructions on how to set up](https://superuser.com/a/527079/50173)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%A IN (%*) DO (set command=!command! %%A)
pdftk.exe %command% cat output "%~dp1binder.pdf"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[pdfsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/) is a multi-platform PDF tool with a pretty comprehensive set of tools for manipulating PDF document orderings. If you can find a way to print off a bunch of PDF documents ([doPDF](http://www.dopdf.com/) is a great PDF "Printer" if you don't already have one), pdfsam will easily merge all the documents into one.