# Batch create PDFs by combining all PDFs in folders

Tags: macos, pdf, batch

I have hundreds of folders full of PDFs. I would like to create a PDF out of each folder called the name of that folder.

For example, "folder_name_1" has 10 PDFs. I want to convert it to a PDF called "folder_name_1.pdf".

I know ways to do it manually, but I'm looking for a way where I can process batch folders at a time.

Possible options I've looked at:

1. Automator - lack expertise here
2. Adobe Acrobat - this is fine for one off, but I don't think I can batch it
3. Terminal - is there a terminal command that will do the trick?

I have reviewed [this](https://superuser.com/questions/389760/adobe-acrobat-how-to-batch-to-combine-multiple-pdf-files) question, and although similar it does not answer how to name the created PDF after the name of the folder.

Update:
Through Automator, I have it setup so all I need to do is drop a folder of PDFs onto it and it will combine, only problem is the renaming. I need it to rename the PDF as the folder name.

See Automator setup below:
[image]

Comment: What operating system are you using (different tools are available, depending)?  The Automator reference seems to imply OS X.

Comment: Yes, OS 10.10.2

Answer (score 1):

See Automator solution below, it saves the input folder name as a variable and then uses it again at the end. Not 100%, but close enough.

[image]