# Merge PDF files with related filenames automatically

Tags: pdf, batch-file, merge, vbscript, combine

I need to merge/combine several PDF files.

What I have is multiple PDF files in one folder. The PDFs that need to be clubbed/combined together would have a partial file name in common; for example:

```
123456_ABCD.pdf
123456_EFGH.pdf
123456_IJKL.pdf
```

The file name would start with numbers then underscore then file name.  I'm going to have hundreds of similar PDFs, and I'm looking for a way to automatically merge these files using a batch script, VBA in Excel, or whatever.

The output of the new file should be in a separate folder with the name `123456.pdf`. I use a Windows OS. I have Adobe Reader, PDF995 and CutePDFwriter installed in my system.

I can manage to get all the pdf's in one main folder. That folder would have multiple pdf's like below.

```
123456_ABCD.pdf
123456_EFGH.pdf
123456_IJKL.pdf
111111_ABCD.pdf
111111_EFGH.pdf
222222_IJKL.pdf
222222_WXYZ.pdf
```

In this scenario the pdf's that I am expecting in the output folder are:

```
123456.pdf
111111.pdf
222222.pdf
```

Comment: Can you please add more example of the folder structure and other pdf that have to be merged separately?

Comment: Thank you @Paul. I can manage to get all the pdf's in one main folder. That folder would have multiple pdf's like below. 
123456_ABCD.pdf
123456_EFGH.pdf
123456_IJKL.pdf
111111_ABCD.pdf
111111_EFGH.pdf
222222_IJKL.pdf
222222_WXYZ.pdf
In this scenario the pdf's that I am expecting in the output folder is
123456.pdf
111111.pdf
222222.pdf.
I am not sure if this would help but the file name would start with numbers then underscore then file name. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Do not add new information in a tiny comment. Simply update your post.

Answer (score 1):

**(Untested)**

1. Download [pdftk](http://portableapps.com/de/apps/office/pdftk_builder_portable) ([direct link here](http://skylink.dl.sourceforge.net/project/portableapps/PDFTK%20Builder%20Portable/PDFTKBuilderPortable_3.8_English.paf.exe)).
2. Extract it somewhere.
3. Put pdftk.exe and the batch together.
4. Then open `cmd` where the batch is located* and run it.
   <sub>* *(shift+RightClic open command prompt here)*</sub>

The script should works if the folder structure is like this:

```
|
+---111111
|       111111_ABCD.pdf
|       111111_EFGH.pdf
|
+---123456
|       123456_ABCD.pdf
|       123456_EFGH.pdf
|       123456_IJKL.pdf
|
\---222222
        222222_IJKL.pdf
        222222_WXYZ.pdf
```

And not in a single folder where all the files are there.

```vb
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem source root folder where to crawl pdfs.
set "source=c:\mydoc\pdf"

rem destination folder
set "destination=c:\mydoc\merged"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad /o:n "%source%"') do (
    set _pdffiles=
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /o:n "%%a\*.pdf"') do (
        set _pdffiles=!_pdffiles! "%%i"
        set "_outputpdf=%%~ni"
    )
    echo pdftk.exe !_pdffiles! cat output "%destination%\!_outputpdf:~0,6!.pdf"
)
```

Remove `echo` if you think the batch is Okay.

Answer largely inspired by [this](https://superuser.com/a/527079)

**Update:**
[There are two answers that complement my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823742/for-loop-group-each-iteration-with-same-prefix-in-one-line)