# Concatenate multiple PDF documents to one single PDF file

Tags: pdf, processing

I have a process to download multiple signed documents with a certificate from a server. These PDFs do not allow for me to combine them into one file.

However, I can combine them into a portfolio, then print them into a flattened PDF via a PDF printer. I can now combine all the PDFs into one document, but leaving them as a portfolio is unacceptable.

Also, I am using Adobe Pro DC. Is there a script that will do this whole process? It is time consuming and seems like something that could be handled with code.

I am using Windows 10, Adobe Acrobat Pro DC Version 2019.012.20040

I am not asking for the actual script, just want to know if it is possible.

Also note, I am a rookie. Tooks some online courses but nothing too advanced

Comment: Please advise which OS you are using, and which version of Adobe Pro DC. Scripts are very specific to the operating system used. Please click [edit] to add that information to your question; please do not use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Comment: Also, we are not a script writing service. What have you tried? How can we help you fix and improve what you've already started?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adobe Acrobat: How to batch to combine multiple pdf files?](https://superuser.com/questions/389760/adobe-acrobat-how-to-batch-to-combine-multiple-pdf-files)

Comment: There's another product, PDF Split and Merge ("PDF SAM"). I believe the pro version may have some scripting ability.