# how do i combine 2 pdf documents into 1 in the terminal?

Tags: terminal, pdf, cat, pandoc

I have 2 files written in Markdown which I used `pandoc` to convert into pdf. I now need to combine the 2 into one single document(lets say I have many that I need to combine into a single pdf). Is there a way  I can do this efficiently from the terminal itself ?

The simplest way I can think of is by `cat` ing the files into one as such

```bsh
cat file1.pdf file2.pdf > file3.pdf
```

But this does not provide the desired result. It only produces the first file (depending on whether I put file1 or file2).

Is there a general way of combining different files into one single "entity" without messing up the pages. Say I had to compile a number of pdf "chapters" into a pdf "book" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adobe Acrobat: How to batch to combine multiple pdf files?](https://superuser.com/questions/389760/adobe-acrobat-how-to-batch-to-combine-multiple-pdf-files)

Comment: This is not a duplicate as OP did not specify Adobe products, and there is a good answer, even if it is not marked as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The usual tool is `pdftk`. This command will take `first.pdf` and `second.pdf`, and create a new `merged.pdf` which is the con`cat`enation of the two source files:

```
pdftk first.pdf second.pdf cat output merged.pdf
```